# Hypersurface with singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, algebraic-surfaces, curves-and-surfaces

I heard once about one open problem. That was about existing a hypersurface of a small degree (5? or 6?) passing through some number (5? 6?) of 3-fold points and 2-fold lines (3 lines?).

It was said that experimentally we can always find such a hypersurface but there is no proof, and counting expected dimension shows that there should be none of them

Do you know exact numbers in this problem,  or some research around?

Comment: Should it be of dimension 2? Does this question related with 3-secant varieties?

Comment: 1) I don't remember. 2) No, I guess. That is about existence of a variety, how would this be related to secant varieties?

Comment: Such kind of varieties can arise in the following context. Let $X\subset \mathbb P^4$ be a surface. Let $S_3$ be a corresponding 3-secant variety and $I_3$ be incidence variety. Due to Severy, the degree $\delta$ of $I_3\to S_3$ is the number apparent triple points of $X$, i.e., the number of triple points of hypersurface $\pi(X)$, where $\pi:\mathbb P^4\to\mathbb P^3$ a projection from a point.

Comment: I invite you to look into http://www.mathnet.or.kr/mathnet/kms_tex/973054.pdf for introduction and into http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870804003482 for developments. See also http://mathsci.kaist.ac.kr/asarc/kwak/paper/smooth.pdf and http://www.dm.unipi.it/~depoi/pubblicazioni/pietro.pdf.

Comment: the question is opposite. One has no intention to study a (particulary defined) variety which are singular (by coincidence). One wants to prove that for a given set of singularities (some number of triple points and double lines) there is no a hypersurface. These are quite different questions. One concerns (particular, though numerous)examples, the other concerns about existence.